# Recordset not updateable for combobox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a combobox that has the following as its rowsource:

```
SELECT qryMIMATRIX.A_JOBNO FROM qryMIMATRIX;
```

**The problem is that the combobox drops down but when I try to select any record, the status bar text is: "Recordset is not updateable"**

qryMIMATRIX:

```
TRANSFORM First(qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_PLANDATE) AS [FirstOfvolgende inspectie]
SELECT qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_ID, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_PLANDATE, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_LOCATION, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_JOBNO, IIf(IsNull(qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_PROJECTID),qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_EQUIPDESCR,"**13M** " & qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_EQUIPDESCR) AS exprA_EQUIPDESCR, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_NENGROUP, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_PRIORITY, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_MENO, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_DAYO
FROM qryMIMATRIXSELECT
GROUP BY qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_ID, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_PLANDATE, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_LOCATION, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_JOBNO, IIf(IsNull(qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_PROJECTID),qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_EQUIPDESCR,"**13M** " & qryMIMATRIXSELECT!A_EQUIPDESCR), qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_NENGROUP, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_PRIORITY, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_MENO, qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_DAYO
ORDER BY qryMIMATRIXSELECT.A_PLANDATE
PIVOT qryMIMATRIXSELECT.periodes In ("0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","20","22","24","26","28","30","32","34","36","38","40","42","44","46","48","50","52");
```

Allow Edits property is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The "Recordset is not updateable" message refers to the form record source, not the query that populates the combo box.

That is, it won't let you select a new value, because you can't edit the query that the form is based on. This is usually due to complicated joins, etc in the query that the form is editing.

Are there other fields on your form that you are able to edit?

Comment: Yes there's another combobox I am able to select value from and it's afterupdate eent works fine.The rowsource of the same is:    select '<ALL>' from qryMIMATRIX union all select qryMIMATRIX.A_LOCATION from qryMIMATRIX

Comment: So dumb of me.I put the name of the column in the control source also and the combobox happens to be in the header section.I just tried keeping the control source blank and it worked.Thanks!